# Is it possible to change the title of a notification?

Tags: python, notifications, pynotify

Is it possible to change the title of a pynotify.Notification? If so what is the method call to use?

Also, it is possible to merge notifications using `set_hint_string('append', '')`. Is it possible to change a title and keep them merged.

I want something like the following (not real code, just a description of the effect) to happen:

```
Notification("Something is happening") + Notification("Something is happening") -> Notification("2 things are happening")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use the `update` method:

```
import pynotify
import time   

pynotify.init('app name')
n=pynotify.Notification("title","Something is happening")
n.show()
time.sleep(2)
n.update("new title","2 things are happening")
n.show()
```